# Recursive function usage help (Mips assembly)

Tags: assembly, mips

I'm studying for an upcoming exam in Mips assembly and im trying to get what the use of this function is. I have followed it step by step , but other than mechanic calculations i cant seem to find the true use of these calculations. Anyone help?

```
func:  
bge $a1, $a2, Exit 
sll $t1, $a1, 2 
add $t1, $a0, $t1 
sll $t2, $a2, 2 
add $t2, $a0, $t2 
lw $t3, 0($t1) 
lw $t4, 0($t2) 
sw $t3, 0($t2) 
sw $t4, 0($t1) 
addi $a1, $a1, 1 
addi $a2, $a2, -1 
j func 
Exit:    
jr $ra
```

Comment: Run it on some sample data and you'll see ;)

Answer (score 0):

It reverses the array given by `$a0` (base address), `$a1` (first element position - 1), and `$a2` (last element position - 1). It does so by repeatedly swapping `array[$a1]` and `array[$a2]` until `$a1 >= $a2`.